# edited-- if statement vba -- how to skip a cell if it has a value

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement, skip

I've edit my original post and given you more details. Basically I have this code:

```
For x = 1 To 1000
If track.Cells(x, 1) = Date Then
    If track.Cells(x, 2) = "EU" Then
        If track.Cells(x, 3) = "ABCDE" Then
           ST.Range("ABCDE").Copy
           EU.Cells(41, 2).PasteSpecial
           Call ActivateSheet
           track.Range(Cells(x, 4), Cells(x, 9)).Copy
               **For i = 42 To 1000
                  If EU.Cells(42 + i, 2) Then
                     EU.Cells(42 + 1, 2).PasteSpecial
                  End If
               Next i**
        End If
    End If    
End If Next x
```

And I'm having problems with this specific part of the code:

```
For i = 42 To 1000
                  If EU.Cells(42 + i, 2) Then
                     EU.Cells(42 + 1, 2).PasteSpecial
                  End If
               Next i
```

What this basically does is copy a range of cells from another worksheet on the same workbook and it should place it on another worksheet. Now, what happens with the code i'm having problems is, I want it to paste to the row below AFTER it pastes the first one. Are there any other ways I can achieve this? I'm only starting to self teach myself in VBA coding. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: has a "string value" versus a "numeric value" or do you mean skip any cell that contains a value of any kind?

Comment: @JGreenwell my bad, i meant skip ay cell that contains a value of any kind.

Comment: For i = 1 To 1000
                    If sheet.Cells(42 + 1, 2) = blank Then
                        sheet.Cells(i + 1, 2).PasteSpecial
                        Else
                        
                        Next i
                    End If

Comment: Please don't use [macros] for MS Office or VBA. [macros tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/macros/info)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to loop the values to find the bottom row, you can simply come from the bottom up in one go.

replace this:

```
**For i = 42 To 1000
   If EU.Cells(42 + i, 2) Then
      EU.Cells(42 + 1, 2).PasteSpecial
   End If
Next i**
```

With this:

```
Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial
```

How it works:

Cells(rows.count,2) is the very last row in the sheet and column 2 (B1048576 nowadays or B65536 in the old days)

.End(XLup) tells it to go up until data, exactly like CTRL-UP in Excel

This tells us the last row that contains data, we don't want to paste here because you will overwrite your last row so:

.offset(1,0) tells it to go ONE row and zero columns away from where it is.

This has worked out the address of where you need to paste, then we pastespecial.

Hope that helps

To actually see how this works go to the immediate window in the VB editor using CTRL-G and paste the following code:

```
?Cells(Rows.Count, 2).address
?Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).address
?Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).address
```

Hit enter after each line and you will see how each added portion of code to the line alters the results

Comment: Happy to help, please flag my answer as correct if you feel that it is the correct one :)

Comment: I did it like this and it's giving the run-time error: application defined or object-defined error

'For x = 1 To 1000
If track.Cells(x, 1) = Date Then
    If track.Cells(x, 2) = "EU" Then
        If track.Cells(x, 3) = "ABCDE" Then
           ST.Range("ABCDE").Copy
           EU.Cells(41, 2).PasteSpecial
           Call ActivateSheet
           track.Range(Cells(x, 4), Cells(x, 9)).Copy
              EU.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(x1Up).Offset(1,0).PasteSpecial
        End If
    End If    
End If 
Next x'

Comment: Put this after PasteSpecial xlPasteAll

Comment: You cant put code in comments, edit your original post and drop it in the bottom of the post :)

Comment: Lol thanks for the tip about posting as code lol. Anyway, I think I know what I did wrong.

Comment: Awesome post back if you get stuck again :)

Comment: Is EU the active sheet? I would imagine not, just put EU. Before the cells statement

Comment: Yes I did that, what happens is after it pastes the copied data on the EU Sheet, it'll return to the very first if statement and eventually will recopy the ST.Range("ABCDE").Copy data and will overwrite the whole thing. ST.Range holds some of the formatted tables I use. i've posted on a different forum before I tried VBA a couple of days ago. here's the link [link](http://www.sevenforums.com/microsoft-office/372909-help-programming-excel-2013-a.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you mean you just want to alter cells that are *empty* you can use `IsEmpty()`, such as:

```vb
For Each cell In rng
    If IsEmpty(cell) Then 'To alter cells containing value use If Not IsEmpty...
    ' Do something
    End If
Next
```

Or if their is the possibility of the *cell values* containing **spaces** you can use

```
If trim(cell & vbnullstring) = vbnullstring Then
' Do something
End If
```

---

To Skip cells that's *value* is of type ***Text*** use `IsText`

```
If Not Application.IsText(cell) Then
' Do Something
End If
```

---

To only alter *values* that **contain only numbers** use `IsNumeric`

```
If IsNumeric(cell) Then
' Do something
End If
```

Comment: Wow thanks for this! I'm pretty much starting to learn VBA and these samples might be very helpful in my learning process. Basically what I need to do is, if that cell has any kind of value in it i want the macro to skip it and proceed on pasting a range of cella into the next row of cells.

Comment: `pasting a range of cella into the next row of cells`------Paste what?